# How to run my mobile automation code (Selenium + Appium) in Amazon cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios

I want to run my mobile automation code on amazon cloud, i was designed my code using Appium and Selenium webdriver.
It's running fine in my local using Emulator or Live device.
My Mobile automation code like :

```
File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "/apps");
    File app = new File(appDir, "/siteaudit.apk");

    System.out.println("Complete path : "+app);

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    //capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "LG_Nexus_4_E960_real");
    //capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Spice Mi-498");
    //capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Nexus 5");

    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "LG Nexus 5");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0");

    capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());

    /*capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "io.appium.android.apis");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".ApiDemos");*/

    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.youtility.attendance.ui");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".ServerURLActivity");


    driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Comment: do you have appium(server) setup at any of your Amazon Cloud machines?

Comment: No ...I am new to work with cloud, can u plz help me out...

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-java-testng.html

Comment: i prepared every thing existed in this link, but that's not for helpful to run the code that's for setup the code..

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, please refer to the [AWS Device Farm TestNG documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-java-testng.html). The two most common problems I've seen are:

- Incorrect packaging of tests and dependencies.
- Setting `DesiredCapabilities`. Device Farm constructs it's own `DesiredCapabilities` prior to test execution; the system behavior is undefined if you have also set values for that object.

I recently [presented a webinar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1D8PM9kdsI) that walks through the creation and execution of Appium tests in Device Farm. I recommend reviewing it for additional guidance.